# Bash manual page selection menu (version 2)

Tags: beginner, bash, shell, macos

This is update to a previously asked question [Bash manual page selection menu](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141494/bash-manual-page-selection-menu). This script generates a menu for the user to select which manual page he/she would like to read.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Mac OS X specific function to clear completely clear the screen.
# Seems to work well for the purposes of this script 
clear(){    
    osascript -e \
    'set theApp to (get the path to the frontmost application) as text
    set this_app to the name of application theApp
    activate application this_app
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down'   
}
clear
COLUMNS=80
while true
do
    printf 'Man Pages: main menu\n¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\n'
    PS3=$'\nMake a selection: '
    select dir in $(ls -d ${PATH//:/ })
    do
        case $REPLY in
            [0-9]*) ls $dir; break 1;;
            *) echo "Exiting" && exit 1;;
        esac
    done
    clear
    printf "Man Pages: $dir"$'\n¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\n'    
    PS3=$'\n(B)ack to main menu\n(Q)uit\n\nMake your selection: '
    while true
    do
        select file in $(ls ${dir} | column -t)
        do
            case $REPLY in
                [0-9]*) man $file; clear; break 1;;
                [bB]) clear; break 2;;
                [qQ]) echo "Exiting" && exit;;
                   *) echo "Exiting" && exit 1;;
            esac
        done
    done
done
```

I wanted to make it so that any programs without a manual page wouldn't be listed in the menu. But to do so would require checking to see if every command found in the user's PATH had a manual page associated with it and then creating a database of commands with manual pages. As it is, if a command does not contain a manual page, the user is directed back to the previous menu page to choose another selection.

I realize there is already a `clear` command in most user's terminals. But the `clear` command in my system clears the screen but still allows the user to scroll up past where the screen was just cleared. I made the `clear` function to completely clear the screen to enhance the overall aesthetic when running the script. It's not really necessary but I think it looks nice.

I think this script does what I intended it to do. So now I'd like other's opinions on it. Is there anything I could do to improve it?